# Maintain Jquery Given Width on Resize

Tags: jquery, html, width

Using JQUERY I take the `width` of a table, divide it by 3 and assign the new width to some `divs`.  This works great. However, when I resize the window (by dragging it) the widths don't continue to work (the `div`s are static, but `myTable`'s width changes) .  How can I get the new widths to be continually updated. Thanks.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() { 

var abc = $('#myTable').width();
var abc = abc/3;
var abc = abc + "px";

$('.facts').css("width",abc);
});
</script>
```

HTML

```
<table id='myTable'></table>
<div class='facts'></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`$(window).resize()`](https://api.jquery.com/resize/):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() { 

  function resizeDiv() {
    var abc = $('#myTable').width();
    var abc = abc/3;
    var abc = abc + "px";
    $('.facts').css("width",abc);
  }
  resizeDiv();

  $(window).resize(resizeDiv);

});
</script>
```

See demo: https://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/aq4nmmwf/